# Infinite Dynamic Button Creation

Tags: vb.net, dynamic

My current assignment involves creating a game in Visual Basic, and I have chosen a basic Idle Game

I'm trying to have the program create a new button every time the total amount of Bits (the unit I'm using as the "currency") is a multiple of 2, without it creating the same button twice, however despite it registering 0 errors the moment the Bit counter hits 2 the program crashes

I'm not very well versed in Visual Basic, as my typical programming language is Python 3.

Code is below, and all named variables have been defined.

```
Private Sub btnSendBit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSendBit.Click
    lblBitAmount.Text = BitTotal + (1 * ClickMult)
    BitTotal += (1 * ClickMult)
    If BitTotal Mod 2 = 0 Then
        Dim btn As Button = New Button
        btn.Location = New Point(128 + (ButtonAmount * 30), 32)
        btn.Name = btnUpgrade(ButtonAmount)
        btn.Text = ButtonAmount & "bits"
        Me.Controls.Add(btn)
        AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf BuyUpgrade
    End If
End Sub

Sub BuyUpgrade()
    BitGain += ButtonAmount
End Sub

Private ReadOnly Property btnUpgrade(buttonAmount As Integer) As String
    Get
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Get
End Property
```

Edit: I read the current comments, and I have to reiterate that I am a total novice with VB. The code I used for the dynamic button generation was copied from elsewhere since I couldn't find any documentation on it in my (admittedly brief) search. I barely understand what each part is supposed to do aside from the explicit stuff like defining the new button and where its located. If someone could explain a fix as though talking to someone with barely any knowledge of the subject it would be very helpful.
Thank you to the people that gave suggestions and pointed out the exception.

Comment: Need a little more info I think such as where exactly it is crashing and what the exception is. a lot of vars there just come out of no where (eg. ButtonAmount ).  Also note you are throwing a NotImplementedException every time the BitTotal is a multiple of 2.  Is that the exception you hitting?

Comment: Of course it crashes. A crash is an unhandled exception. Gee, I wonder where an exception could be thrown in that code. Maybe it's the line that explicitly throws an exception! The whole point of the `Throw New NotImplementedException()` is to tell you that you're trying to call a method that is not implemented. The solution, not surprisingly, is to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gridview connected to a database:
1- Use the database to increment  and display the number of buttons
2- Use Gridview specifications (No borders, no headers,...)
3- Every time the user will click the button, the database will save an additional number (Incremnetly) and using data-bind, you can refresh the table.
4- Use the Gridview row method to control every button